# What is this technique to resize the images proportionally used by google chrome new tab?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, xhtml

I saw this code in Google Chrome **Beta** version's new tab where it show the icon if installed tabs.

[image]

They are using any technique to resize the images.

this is html of a icon

```
<div class="app-img-container launch-click-target" title="Box Office" style="height: 97.56981132075472px; width: 97.56981132075472px; ">
    <img class="" src="chrome://extension-icon/dhbbohlkjglcppclgngklojecglglinl/128/0">
  </div>
```

and it's css of related classes

```
.app-img-container {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
-webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
}

.app-img-container > * {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone tell me which method they are using? Is it based on Javascript?

To check this you can install [Google Chrome Beta](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) and install some apps from chrome store then open a new tab in chrome. you will se the icons.

**Note: it's only works in Beta version**

**This is the whole source of Tab page which I took from view source**
http://jsbin.com/ikituc/edit#html

**And this is rendred source which i copied from Chrome Developer tools HTML tab**
http://jsbin.com/ekiqaf/edit#html

I want to know the method which is being used to re-size the icons.

Comment: do View Source on the new tab page and look at the javascript (CTRL+F: `width =`)

Comment: App icons are not re-sizable in Chrome, you need to include different sizes in your app manually.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by resizable? There is no resizable icon here in Canary. If you mean resizing from small icons to big icons I should say there is two different icons for every app. For example for Angry Birds:

```
chrome://extension-icon/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj/16/1

chrome://extension-icon/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj/128/0
```

Any other "resize" is because of CSS3 transitions

Answer (score 2):

The method is surely based on javascrip.
If you take a look at the `calculateLayout_` method you will understand why :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a JS + CSS powered solution.

```
<div class="app-img-container launch-click-target" title="Chrome Web Store" 
 style="height: 67.98490566037735px; width: 67.98490566037735px; ">
    <img class="" src="chrome://theme/IDR_WEBSTORE_ICON">
  <img class="apps-promo-logo">
</div>
```

chrome://newtab/ source:

```
.app-img-container > * {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

They set the width of .app-img-container programatically, image gets this width with CSS.