# How to use javascript conditionally like CSS3 media queries, orientation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How to use javascript conditionally like CSS3 media queries, orientation?

For Example I can write css for specific

```
@media only screen and (width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {

.selector1 { width:960px}

}
```

Now I want to only run some javascript if it match the same conditions

like

```
@media only screen and (width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {

A javascript code here

}
```

**I have a external javascript for example `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js` and it should be only run on specific screen size and orientation**

Comment: Why would you want jQuery to only run on one size and orientation?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the orientation or size changes after loading? (device rotated, window resized, etc)

Comment: i want to use a image resize jquery plugin only if max-width:1025px and max-width:2048px

Comment: You should include the library no matter what. Just don't use the functions unless the screen is of the correct size

Comment: @Eric - this is the plugin which I want to use to image re-sizing http://www.ollicle.com/projects/jquery/imagefit/eg/ only if max-width:1025px and max-width:2048px Why I'm using this plugin because I don't know the technique used by google chrome new tab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613810/what-is-this-technique-to-resize-the-images-proportionally-used-by-google-chrome

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how jQuery plugins work. By default, they _don't actually do anything_. All they do is include some code that allows you to do something. In the case of your plugin, `$(selector).imagefit()` does the magic.

Comment: @Jitendra: Here's a better way to resize images for mobile phones: http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/

Comment: I would recommend not including the library just to include it. Adding a reference to the library and not using it only bloats the packets being requested and sent to the client.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? It has 42 votes, so I think it should be considered the best one.

Answer (score 66):

You can use [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

**Test a mobile device media query**

```
if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 480px)').matches) {
  // smartphone/iphone... maybe run some small-screen related dom scripting?
}
```

**Test landscape orientation**

```
if (matchMedia('all and (orientation:landscape)').matches) {
  // probably tablet in widescreen view
}
```

Currently supported in all modern browsers ([more details](https://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia))

Polyfill for old browsers: 
https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: There is a video from Google that explain That : http://youtu.be/svEg7MiqGf8?t=3m4s

Comment: I think [`matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is javascript native function.

Answer (score 12):

> ...I want to run a javascript only if max-width of browser is 1900px
>   and min-width is 768

**EDIT:** Actually, that was all wrong. If you're using a mobile device, use:

```
function doStuff(){
    landscape = window.orientation? window.orientation=='landscape' : true;

    if(landscape && window.innerWidth<1900 && window.innerWidth > 768){
        //code here
    }
}
window.onload=window.onresize=doStuff;
if(window.onorientationchange){
    window.onorientationchange=doStuff;
}
```

Comment: **+1** Probably a cleaner way of doing it than my way.

Comment: can i put a external javascript inside it?

Comment: This does not take into account the orientation change.

Comment: @Jitendra: You don't have to! Just let the plugin run anyway, and put `$('img').imagefit()` inside it.

Comment: @EmilStenström, Is everyone here talking about with handheld devices? If you are, then it's been going over my head this entire time.

Comment: @Walkerneo: The original question has orientation: landscape, so I assume that the js in question should only run in that orientation.

Comment: Scroll bars throw this out

Answer (score 11):

I can think of a quick solution: Apply some styles conditionally to an invisible div, and check if they are applied with javascript:

```
div#test { display: none }
@media only screen and (width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    div#test { background-color: white; }
}
```

```
if(document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor == 'white')
    mediaSelectorIsActive();
```

Comment: +1 Just finished typing a similar answer, but you were faster.

Comment: That's what I said, but I think the problem is that the CSS executes instantly based on this example: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/

Which would mean that it wouldn't be instant and you would have to keep checking.

Comment: I guess my answer is just invisible?

Comment: @Walkerneo: CSS executing instantly is good! That'd make it happen before the javascript! As for your answer, it's just too vague.

Comment: @Walkerneo - you are right. I want to run a javascript only if max-width of browser is 1900px and min-width is 768.

Comment: No, I mean it responds to the content. Did you see the example with the chameleon? It changes colors when you resize the window. The CSS takes effect instantly.

Comment: This means you have to select a random element and change its style to execute some javascript. Doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: @Walkerneo: That's a problem with the original question. The asker hasn't specified what they want to happen if the window is resized. You can't "un-run" the script, and it would probably be a bad idea to rerun it every time the window is resized.

Comment: @JitendraVyas, What exactly do you mean by that? You can use window.offsetWidth to check the width of their window. You can use window.onresize to check if, after the resize, it's the correct dimensions

Comment: @Eric - Can you please answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613810/what-is-this-technique-to-resize-the-images-proportionally-used-by-google-chrome in the Chrome tab , the icons only start to scale after `768px` and only scale up-to `1200px`. after `1200px` and before `768px` icons doesn't scale

Comment: What do you want to happen if they're not on a mobile device?

Comment: @Walkerneo - on mobile device I would not re-size the picture. So i will not need any javascript condition

Comment: @JitendraVyas, but your example code checks for window orientation, which only exists in mobile devices...

Comment: @Walkerneo - yes I'm considering iPad but not iphone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3961/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-walkerneo)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth mentioning that there is the orientationchange event that you might want to hook into like so:

```
$('body').bind('orientationchange', function(){
    // check orientation, update styles accordingly
});
```

I know that about this event being fired by mobile Safari, you'd have to check about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rewrite the media query as a javascript expression instead:

```
function sizehandler(evt) {
    ...
}

function orientationhandler(evt){  

  // For FF3.6+  
  if (!evt.gamma && !evt.beta) {  
    evt.gamma = -(evt.x * (180 / Math.PI));  
    evt.beta = -(evt.y * (180 / Math.PI));  
  }  

  // use evt.gamma, evt.beta, and evt.alpha   
  // according to dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation  

  ...
}  

window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', orientationhandler, false);
window.addEventListener('MozOrientation', orientationhandler, false);
window.addEventListener('load', orientationhandler, false); 
window.addEventListener('resize', sizehandler, false); 
window.addEventListener('load', sizehandler, false);
```

Comment: orientationhandler code comes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/detecting_device_orientation#section_4

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way I found is to get the width of our page; then to conditionally use it.

```js
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (x < 992) {     
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```