# wordpress mobile detection load specific JS

Tags: javascript, mobile, wordpress, tablet

I would like to know is there any wordpress plugin or codes to detect the user using mobile/tablet and load some specific javascript?

I found online that there are some WP plugin to load theme when detected as mobile. 
But is there any way to load javascript rather than themes?

Comment: This seems relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625718/how-to-use-javascript-conditionally-like-css3-media-queries-orientation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an external plugin for something, which is *already* implemented in WordPress system.

You can use the `wp_is_mobile();` conditional tag to check if the user is visiting using a mobile device. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you can place it in your `header.php` and then redirect the users to the proper content.

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff or redirect here */
  wp_redirect( $location, $status );
  exit;

} ?>
```

Comment: this is nice !! wp_redirect($location, $status); is not necessary d right?

Comment: Nope, it is not necessary if you do not want to redirect your visitors to different (mobile perhaps) part of your website.