# CSS solution for surplus/overflow of tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The design team for my project created a mockup for a tab component solution.  In the mockup, if there are a surplus of tabs - meaning there are more tabs than can fit in the available horizontal space - any tab(s) that would be truncated is removed and placed in a flyout/drop down menu.  Here is an example where there are 6 tabs, but the last three would be truncated given the screen size:

[image]

Here is some sample markup:

```
<div class="tabs-container">    
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button type="button">Tab 1</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button">Tab 2</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button">Tab 3</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-panel is-active">Tab 1 Content</div>
    <div class="tabs-panel">Tab 2 Content</div>
    <div class="tabs-panel">Tab 3 Content</div>
</div>
```

I'm currently using the `react-tabs` library to render my tabs, but the feature described above is not part of that solution.  This feature could be accomplished with plain javascript/jQuery, but that would be non-ideal.

**Can this be accomplished with HTML/CSS or even ReactJS?**

Comment: You could use media queries to show/hide different layouts of the same content based on available screen width.

Comment: In React you could measure the screen size and then conditionally render each tab to the desired location.

Comment: @Toby How can you measure screen size in React?

Comment: It's no different in React than it would be in JavaScript - `window.width`. Alternatively, you can use something a [little more advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625718/how-to-use-javascript-conditionally-like-css3-media-queries-orientation).

Comment: @Toby Duh. Sorry. Not sure this or even Pointy's solution is a reasonable because tab header text can be any width. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: A CSS media query will blindly alter the layout regardless of independent tab size - JS will allow you fine grain control over exactly how you render the tabs based upon each tab's width. Read the link in my last comment.

Comment: I'm not sure this requires a full answer, so I'll just comment - it's not possible with CSS _alone_. Using JS, as @Toby suggested, is the right path to take.