# How do I replace an HTML element depending on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to replace a `<ol>` element with a `<ul>` element by media query, so when the user is in desktop mode the result should be like this:

```html
    <ol>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ol>
```

but in mobile it should be:

```html
    <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ul>
```

It is possible to do this by media query or jQuery?

Comment: Why does the order of the list items have significance when the user has a desktop, but when on mobile the order of **same** data suddenly doesn't matter? (Note that changing the HTML changes the *meaning* and if you just want to change the *presentation* then ask about that)

Comment: Switching the CSS property `list-style-type` between `disc` and `decimal` on the `<ul>` **or** `<ol>` with a media query will achieve that, style-wise -> https://jsfiddle.net/twc3sey2/

Comment: i added a plugin that allow the user to sort the list dragging (that works only in desktop but not in mobile using <ol>) at the same time in mobile the <li> tags, which has links inside does not work with <ol> tags, only with <ul> ones, so thats why i need to change the tags for mobile devices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use javascript conditionally like CSS3 media queries, orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625718/how-to-use-javascript-conditionally-like-css3-media-queries-orientation)

Comment: I suspect that you've asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Instead, ask for a solution to your _actual_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if its possible but you can use a class for each and manipulate they with displays:

```
<ol class="first-list">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>

<ul class="second-list">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

And on CSS:

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    .first-list{
        display:none;
    }
    .second-list{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Of course you can put in `max-width` what you need.

Comment: I think that this is not entirely true.. Since the contents of the lists (`<li>` tags) should be the **same**, but not duplicates.

Comment: Yes, that's a disadvantage.

Comment: thanks, its duplicated but it works for now!!

Comment: Yes, its not a good practice to have duplicated elements. You can use javascript to achieve it too. Don't forget accept the answer if this helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of having multiple(ol list and ul list).. just change the disc-type base on media query so:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  ol {
    list-style-type: disc
  }
}
```

Which means its OL(decimals) and when it hits certain media query(mobile) it is still OL but the type can change to `disc` . Unless you need both actual ol/ul then this is your best bet.