# Using media query to run <script> only in desktop

Tags: html, css

I want to run `<script type="text/javascript" src="#" data-cfasync="false" async="async"></script>` only in desktop devices. I tried with

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="example"><script type="text/javascript" src="#" data-cfasync="false" async="async"></script></div>
```

but didn't work. So What do you goes think? How can i achive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use javascript conditionally like CSS3 media queries, orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625718/how-to-use-javascript-conditionally-like-css3-media-queries-orientation)

Comment: Does `display` read `run` to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's **impossible**.
You cannot use a media query to do that (or any CSS in general).

`display: none;` simply means that the content is not rendered in the browser.

`display: none;` lets you turn off the display of an element and all descendant elements. But if you take a look at the DOM of the page using the dev tools, the element with display none and his child elements are there in the DOM tree.

So we can conclude that it will **not prevent** the browser from **parsing** and then **loading** that markup and associated resources; your script will be always loaded and your media query and display style won't do anything.

You should check it in your own script if the device is a desktop.
If that script is from a third-party, you should create your own script, check if the device is a desktop, and then load the third-party script if the device is actually a desktop.

Regarding how to detect if a device is a desktop, I'll leave here a couple of answers that have tons of resources to choose from (a device might be either mobile or desktop):

[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

Answer (score 3):

You Can use matchMedia() method of javascript to detect a mobile device. if the media queries match then create another script html element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
<script>
    let matchMedia = window.matchMedia("(max-width:600px)");
    if(matchMedia.matches){
        alert("This is mobile device so script not supported");
    }
    else{
       let x = document.createElement("script");
       x.src="ex.js"//your script path will goes gere
       document.querySelector("html").append(x);

    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Sundeep Sharma, you're answer solved it. I had the same problem and after using your solution it's now working properly on mobile and desktop. You're answer should be the marked one.